# Rails 3: error while passing params to javascript function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I am trying to pass value to the JavaScript function but it gives me the below error on Firebug when I click the anchor tag (plus icon).

What I am trying to do is, on click of a 'plus' sign, I add fields from partial to the table. What am I doing wrong here?

Currently there is a table with '+' inside `<th>`. I want to append data(from the partial) to the table.

**Error**

```
SyntaxError: syntax error
[Break On This Error]   

add_fields(this, contact, &quot;&lt;tr class=\&#x27;fields\&#x27;&gt;\n&lt;td&gt...
```

**Helper file**

```
module TestHelper
    def add_fields(name, obj)

        if (obj == 'contact')
            fields = render :partial => '/test/add_fields', :locals => {:map_values => ["Name", "URL", "Address"]}  
            link_to_function(name, h("add_fields(this, #{obj}, \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")"))

        elsif (obj=='company')
            fields = render :partial => '/test/add_fields', :locals => {:map_values => ["CName", "CURL", "CAddress"]}   
            link_to_function(name, h("add_fields(this, #{obj}, \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")"))
        elsif (obj=='lead')
            fields = render :partial => '/test/add_fields', :locals => {:map_values => ["LName", "LURL", "LAddress"]}   
            link_to_function(name, h("add_fields(this, \"#{obj}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")"))
        end

    end
end
```

**View file**

```
=add_fields 'Add', 'contact'
```

**partial _add_fields.html.haml**

```
%tr.fields
  %td
    %select{:class => 'select-two'}
      - map_values.each do |e|
        %option #{e}
```

**js file**

```
add_fields = function(obj, maptype, content){

  //console.log(obj.closest('.table'));
  var parent = $(obj).closest('.table');
  var msg_obj = $('.alert.alert-info',parent);
  if(msg_obj.length > 0) {
    msg_obj.closest('tr').addClass('hidden');
  }

  $('tbody',parent).append(content);
  $("select.select-two").select2({allowClear: true});

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the below line

```
    link_to_function(name, h("add_fields(this, \"#{obj}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")"))
```

to

```
    link_to_function("name", "add_fields(this, '#{obj}', '#{j(fields)}'
)".html_safe)
```

h() function is out dated in rails 3

use `raw "string"`

or `"string".html_safe`